# AWS S3: Bulk move files within bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I have many files (millions) spread around numerous folders (hundreds of thousands) in a S3 bucket and I need to rename all folders according to a custom mapping.

I'm aware there's no rename method so I'll have to copy and delete. I can currently do that by looping on all my objects and copying with a new prefix, but that's way to slow.

I guess I'm looking to perform a bulk operation somehow, but I couldn't find a way to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Will `aws s3 mv` command help?

To see if it will do the trick, try it with `dryrun` first:

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucketname/the/original/path/ s3://bucketname/the/new/path/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*whatever_common_part_of_name*.*" --dryrun
```

Comment: It could have helped, but in this case I needed to move the files to different paths depending on the file name so the single move command wasn't that helpful
(if I remember correctly I ended up running a script to move files one by one)